# Remove entries of one text file present in another

Tags: powershell

I have 2 text file like below

```
exclude.txt

10.1.1.3
10.1.1.4
10.1.1.5
10.1.1.6
```

```
free.txt
10.1.1.3
10.1.1.4
10.1.1.5
10.1.1.6
10.1.1.7
10.1.1.8
10.1.1.9
10.1.1.10
```

I want to write exclude the entries of **exclude.txt** from **free.txt** and write to another file

```
10.1.1.7
10.1.1.8
10.1.1.9
10.1.1.10
```

I tried :

```
compare-object  (get-content $freeips) (get-content $excludeip) -PassThru | format-list | Out-File $finalips
```

Here in the final output I am always getting the first IP of the **exclude.txt**

```
10.1.1.7
10.1.1.8
10.1.1.9
10.1.1.10
10.1.1.3
```

and another way I tried

```
$exclude = Get-Content "C:\exclude.txt"

foreach($ip in $exclude)
{
    get-content "C:\free.txt" | select-string -pattern $ip -notmatch | Out-File "C:\diff.txt"
}
```

But in this case also I am getting the entries of **exclude.txt** in the final output.

Please let me know where I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`Select-String`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) solution is probably faster. Besides it doesn't require the iteration through the IP addresses as the `-Pattern` parameters accepts a string array (`String[]`). The point is thou that by default the pattern(s) repressent a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) where a dot (`.`) is a place holder for any character. To search for a literal pattern you should use the `-SimpleMatch` switch:

```
$exclude = Get-Content .\exclude.txt
get-content .\free.txt |Select-String -pattern $exclude -NotMatch -SimpleMatch
```

**Note:** The space in top of the displayed `exclude.txt` file suggests that there might be an empty line in top of the file (which `regex` matches any string). To get rid of any empty lines, use:

```
$exclude = Get-Content .\exclude.txt |Where-Object { $_ }
```

Answer (score 0):

When comparing, `$excludeip` should be the referenceObject and `$freeips` comes after, like this:

```
compare-object (get-content $excludeip) (get-content $freeips) -PassThru | Out-File $finalips
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it is still adding the exclude file IP to the final output

Comment: Sorry. When comparing, $excludeip should be the referenceObject and $freeips comes second then. I will edit my answer.